# ASP.NET get text from Gridviewrow cell with findControl

Tags: asp.net

Simple question I think. I have a gridviewrow and i want to be able to put the text from a cell into a textbox on my page. The row is from a table where the column is called "Title" and is of type nvarchar(100). I tried something like this but it's giving me a null string;

```
      tBox.Text = ((TextBox)selectedRow.FindControl("Title")).ToString();
```

I know I can just use the cell value, but I thought this would be useful to know.
Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's the right idea, just a little bit off:

`row.FindControl("columnName")`

Gives you an actual object. Exactly what it returns depends on what is specified in the ASP portion. Could be a label, could be a text box, checkbox...

After you have the object, you can access the properties as you normally would. In this case, you'll probably want the `Text` property.

`row.FindControl("...").Text`

If you'd rather use position indexes, something like this also works:

`row.Cells[i].Controls[1]`

Where `i` is the 0 based index for the item, starting from the left.

Answer (score 0):

i don't get the way you get ur selected index, but in any cases first you have to get this textbox into textbox variable then pass the text inside it to the textbox of ur page like this:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)selectedRow.FindControl("Title");
if(tb != null){
   tBox.Text = tb.Text;
}
```

also selectedRow can be from a for loop on the rows of the gridview or you can get it from function like editing row or updating row or row data bound,through e.RowIndex